# Go back through items in a array on click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi I am trying to create a slider using just javascript, I placed my images in a array. I have so far made it work with the "next" button but I am struggling with the "previous" button, I am not sure how to start. I am new to javascript so if my code is very inefficient please let me know.

This is what I have used for the "next" button

```
function slideRight() {
    index++
    if(index >= slideList.length){
        index = 0;
        slideList[2].style.display = 'none'; 
        circle[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        circle[2].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }

    slideList[index].style.display = 'block'; 
    slideList[index-1].style.display = 'none'; 

    circle[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    circle[index-1].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

I have tried using decrement but that doesn't work.

Here is a fiddle with the full code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwfkgfaf/2/)

Comment: Why are you making your own? There are literally 100s of solutions for javascript sliders :) I highly recogment finding one that fits your needs :)

Comment: Hi, I know but I wanted to practice as I am trying to improve my coding :)

Comment: Always a good thing :) lemme just try to give you an answer.

Comment: Other answers are just large heaps of code. Check out mine, I hope it gets you further in your learning. Good luck and happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize it to use only one function for both jobs, with this (see it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/y3x6gv4s/1/)):

```
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"),//getting slide class as node list
    circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle"),
    slideList = [slide[0],slide[1],slide[2]], //storing each image using nodelist index 
    buttonL = document.getElementById('bt1'),
    buttonR = document.getElementById('bt2'),
    index = 0;

slideList[0].style.display = 'block'; //first slide 

//function which display div to indicate what slide is showing
(function displayCircle() { 
    var circleContainer = document.getElementById('circleContainer'),
        circleHtml ='',
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++) {
        circleHtml += '<div class="circle"></div>';
    }
    circleContainer.innerHTML = circleHtml;
}());

circle[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //first light

function slideIt(direction) {
    previous = index;

    if (direction == 'right') {
        index++;
        if (index >= slideList.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    } else {
        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = slideList.length-1;
        }
    }

    slideList[index].style.display = 'block'; 
    slideList[previous].style.display = 'none'; 

    circle[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    circle[previous].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

buttonR.addEventListener('click', function(){ slideIt('right'); }, false);
buttonL.addEventListener('click', function(){ slideIt('left'); }, false);
```

Comment: Hello, I wanted to know why does previous and index have different values when you move right once if they are equal to each other? When I move right once, index has a value of 1 and previous 2 .

Comment: *sorry ignore the last bit

Comment: First of all you assign `previous = index` to remember where you were. Then you move `index` to the desired direction (`index++` or `index--`). At this point, `previous` and `index` will have different values. Then comes the sanity check: `index` can't be greater than `slideList.length-1` nor less than `0`. After that you just change the style of both `previous` and `index`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"),//getting slide class as node list
    circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle"),
    slideList = [slide[0],slide[1],slide[2]], //storing each image using nodelist index 
    buttonL = document.getElementById('bt1'),
    buttonR = document.getElementById('bt2'),
    index = 0;

slideList[0].style.display = 'block'; //first slide 

//function which display div to indicate what slide is showing
(function displayCircle() { 
    var circleContainer = document.getElementById('circleContainer'),
        circleHtml ='',
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < slideList.length; i++) {
        circleHtml += '<div class="circle"></div>';
    }
    circleContainer.innerHTML = circleHtml;
}());

circle[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //first light

function slideRight() {
    var prev = index++;
    if(index >= slideList.length){
        index = 0;
    }
    
    slideList[index].style.display = 'block'; 
    slideList[prev].style.display = 'none'; 
    
    circle[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    circle[prev].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

function slideLeft() {
    var prev = index--;
    if(index < 0){
        index = slideList.length - 1;
    }
    
    slideList[index].style.display = 'block'; 
    slideList[prev].style.display = 'none'; 
    
    circle[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    circle[prev].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}


buttonR.addEventListener('click', slideRight, false);
buttonL.addEventListener('click', slideLeft, false);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

main {
    height: inherit;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
}

#sliderContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.slide {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    
}

.btcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22%;
    height: 100%;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: black;
}

#circleContainer {
    text-align: center;
    height: 5%;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 1.5%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="btcontainer" id="btC2">
            <div class="button" id="bt1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sliderContainer">
            <ul id="slideGroup">
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/examples/1.jpg" /></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.phpf1.com/images/maxSlideShow/slideshow.jpg" /></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.welie.com/patterns/images/slideshow-pro.png" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="btcontainer" id="btC2">
            <div class="button" id="bt2"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="circleContainer"></div>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What kind of answer is this? Just throw some code in and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code. You can also modularize the code add one listenerfunction which takes an argument + or - to scroll right /left

```js
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slide"),//getting slide class as node list
circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle"),
index = 0;

//function which display div to indicate what slide is showing
(function displayCircle() { 
    var circleContainer = document.getElementById('circleContainer'),
        circleHtml ='',
        i;
        for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
            circleHtml += '<div class="circle"></div>';
        }
    circleContainer.innerHTML = circleHtml;
    
}());

slide[0].style.display = 'block'; //first slide 
circle[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //first light
function slideImg(dir) {
    var lastIndex = index;
    index = dir==='+' ? (++index > slide.length-1 ? 0 : index) : (--index < 0 ? slide.length-1 : index);
    
    
    slide[index].style.display = 'block'; 
    slide[lastIndex].style.display = 'none'; 

    circle[index].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    circle[lastIndex].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click', (function(){slideImg('+');}), false);
document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click', (function(){slideImg('-');}), false);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

main {
    height: inherit;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
}

#sliderContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.slide {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    
}

.btcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22%;
    height: 100%;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: black;
}

#circleContainer {
    text-align: center;
    height: 5%;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 1.5%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="btcontainer" id="btC2">
            <div class="button" id="bt1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sliderContainer">
            <ul id="slideGroup">
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/examples/1.jpg" /></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.phpf1.com/images/maxSlideShow/slideshow.jpg" /></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.welie.com/patterns/images/slideshow-pro.png" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="btcontainer" id="btC2">
            <div class="button" id="bt2"></div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="circleContainer"></div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function slideLeft() {
    index--;
    if(index < 0){
        index = slideList.length;
    }
   // whatever else you need to do to slide it ;)
}
```

I think the `index < 0` part should get you a long way.
the index-- decreases your index, then if it falls below 0 (your first 1) the index will be set to the last one.